# What do I do if the quarried stone next to my house stops giving me quarried stone? Kinda confused

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I need help because my quarried stone next to my house in Falkreath stopped giving me stone

Comment: What did you use all the stone on? To build all three houses you need perhaps 800 quarried stone, but not much more.

Answer (score 4):

Stone quarries will yield 4000 units before exhausting. So in your case you will have to find other stone quarries.

You can find a complete list of locations for [quarried stones here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Quarried_Stone).